# Is there a way to find out which partition is the message written if using EventHub.SendAsync(EventData)?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is there a way to find out which partition is the message written if using EventHub.SendAsync(EventData) from Azure EventHub client SDK ?

We intentionally do not provide a partition key so EventHub service can do its internal load balancing but want to find out which partition the data is written to eventually, for diagnosing issues with the end to end data flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan's answer is correct in the context of the legacy SDK *(`Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs`)*, but the current generation *(`Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`)* is slightly different.  You don't mention a specific language, but conceptually the answer is the same across them. I'll use .NET to illustrate.

If you're not using a call that requires specifying a partition directly when reading events, then you'll always have access to an object that represents the partition that an event was read from.   For example, if you're using the [EventHubConsumerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.eventhubconsumerclient?view=azure-dotnet) method [ReadEventsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.eventhubconsumerclient.readeventsasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Consumer_EventHubConsumerClient_ReadEventsAsync_System_Boolean_Azure_Messaging_EventHubs_Consumer_ReadEventOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) to explore, you'll be see the [PartitionEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.consumer.partitionevent?view=azure-dotnet) where the `Partition` property tells you the partition that the `Data` was read from.

When using the [EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient?view=azure-dotnet), your [ProcessEventAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventprocessorclient.processeventasync?view=azure-dotnet) handler will be invoked with a set of [ProcessEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.processor.processeventargs?view=azure-dotnet) where the `Partition` property tells you the partition that the `Data` was read from.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to this. But there're 2 workarounds.

1.Use the [Event Hubs Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-enable-through-portal) to store the incoming events, then check the events in the specified blob storage. When the events are stored in blob storage, the path contains the partition id, so you can know it.

2.Use code. Create a new Consumer Group, and follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-get-started-send-legacy#receive-events) to read events. And in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-get-started-send-legacy#implement-the-ieventprocessor-interface), there is a method `public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)`. You can take use of the parameter `PartitionContext` to get the event's partition id(by using `context.PartitionId`).

Comment: You may want to consider making it clear that #2 is based on a legacy version of the SDK; we'd recommend new development make use of Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.